# Select data till the end based on a pattern in one column

Tags: r, stringr

I have messy data. I want to subset the data based on a phrase in a column till the end.

```
df1 <- data.frame(
V1=c("No. de Control Interno de", "la Partida / Concepto de Obra","",
     "LO-009J0U004-","E50-2021",""),
V2=c("","Descripción Breve","Trabajos de señalamiento horizontal en puente de",
     "cuota \"El Zacatal\", consistentes en suministro y","aplicación de pintura de tránsito, suministro y",
     "colocación de botones y ménsulas reflejantes."),
V3=c("","ClaveCUCOP","","","62502002",""),
V4=c("Unidad","Observaciones de Medida","","","Obra",""),
V5=c("","Cantidad","","","1","")
)
```

Whenver in `V2`, there is the phrase `Descripción`, the code should subset dataframe from that row till the end. For example, in the case above, this means selecting data from row 2 till row 6. I was trying with `str_detect` from `stringr` package.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `which()` function to return the indices where `str_detect()` is `TRUE`.

```
library(stringr)

which(str_detect(df1$V2, "Descripción"))
[1] 2
```

If instead you save the output of `which()` to a variable, you can use it to subset your data. Note that the follow explicitly calls the first value in `x` in case there are more than one place `str_detect` returns true.

```
x <- which(str_detect(df1$V2, "Descripción"))
df1[x[1]:nrow(df1),]
```

> ```
>                              V1                                               V2         V3                      V4       V5
> 2 la Partida / Concepto de Obra                                Descripción Breve ClaveCUCOP Observaciones de Medida Cantidad
> 3                               Trabajos de señalamiento horizontal en puente de                                            
> 4                 LO-009J0U004- cuota "El Zacatal", consistentes en suministro y                                            
> 5                      E50-2021  aplicación de pintura de tránsito, suministro y   62502002                    Obra        1
> 6                                  colocación de botones y ménsulas reflejantes.
> ```

Comment: There is `str_which` `str_which(df1$V2, "Descripción")#
[1] 2`